# solving recursively

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

The functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and $g : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ are recursively defined as follows:

- $f(0) =1$,
- $f(1) =2$,
- $f(n) = g(f(n − 2),f(n − 1))$   if $n \ge 2$,
- $g(m,0) =2m $   if $m \ge 0$,
- $g(m,n) =g(m,n − 1) + 1$   if $m \ge 0$ and $n \ge 1$.

Solve these recurrences for $f$, i.e., express $f(n)$ in terms of $n$. Justify your answer

**Solution**: so I got the $g$ pattern and proved it to be right $g(m,n)= 2m+n$
now for $f(n)$ I got $f(n)= 2f(n-1)$.
Here I want to get rid of $f(n-1)$, I am stuck here. Can anyone help how to move forward?

Comment: The sequence that multiply itself by 2 every time with $f(0)=1$ is basically just $f(n)=2^n$.

Comment: So does that mean f(n) = 2^n. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right. .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we get closed form of $g$:
$$
g(m,n) = g(m, n-1) + 1 = g(m,0) + n = 2m + n,\\ 
$$
so $f(n) = f(n-1) + 2f(n-2)$. Now one may see that as $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 2 = 2f(0)$ we get $f(2) = 2f(0) + 2f(0) = 2f(1) = 4$, $f(3) = 2f(2) = 8$ etc., i.e. $f(n) = 2^n$ which is easy to prove by induction.

But there is more general approach to solve such kind of recursions. If we denote $f_n = f(n)$, we have the recurrent formula $f_{n+2} - f_{n+1} - 2f_n = 0 $. Each root $\lambda$ of its characteristic equation $x^2 - x - 2 = 0$ solves this recurrent formula by $f_n = \lambda^n$. General solution for recurrence sequence may be represented as linear combination of such "simple" solutions, i.e. if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are roots of characteristic equation, the general solution has the form $f_n = \alpha_1\lambda_1^n + \alpha_2\lambda_2^n$. In our case $\lambda_1 = -1$, $\lambda_2 = 2$, so $f_n = \alpha_1(-1)^n + \alpha_22^n$. To know $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ we may use initial values of $f_n$:
$$
f_0 = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 1, \\
f_1 = -\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 = 2,
$$
so $\alpha_1 = 0$ and $\alpha_2 = 1$ which gives the same answer $f_n = 2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

By freezing $m$, you easily solve the recursion on $g$, giving $g(m,n)=2m+n$. Then you get the more interesting

$$f(n)=2f(n-2)+f(n-1).$$

You can rewrite it

$$f(n)+f(n-1)=2f(n-2)+2f(n-1)=2(f(n-2)+f(n-1)),$$

leading, by induction, to the solution

$$f(n)+f(n-1)=(f(1)+f(0))\,2^{n-1}=3\cdot2^{n-1}.$$

Now, "cheating" a little more, we observe that

$$f(n)+f(n-1)=2^n+2^{n-1}$$ and

$$f(n)=2^n$$ is compatible with the initial conditions.